# Only few pages are able to appear after compiling

Tags: texshop

As I run `main.tex` file, few pages are appear as output and rest of the pages are not able appear.

Following is `main.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\date{02 March 2020}

\begin{document}

\input{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\chapter*{Dedication}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication}

\chapter*{Declaration}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}

\chapter*{Abstract}
\input{chapters/abstract_v3}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

\chapter*{Foreword}
\input{chapters/foreword}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword}

\chapter*{Introduction}
\input{chapters/introduction_v2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Computers for Children}
\input{chapters/chapter1_v1}

\chapter{Methophobia}
\input{chapters/chapter2_v1}

\chapter{Languages for Computers and for People}
\input{chapters/chapter3_v1}

\chapter{Microworlds:Incubators for Knowledge}
\input{chapters/chapter4_v1}

\chapter{LOGO's Roots:Piaget and AI}
\input{chapters/chapter5_v1}

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}

In 1964 I moved from one world to another. For the previous five years I had lived in Alpine villages near Geneva, Switzerland, where I worked with Jean Piaget. The focus of my attention was on children, on the nature of thinking, and on how children become thinkers. I moved to MIT into an urban world of cybernetics and computers. My attention was still focused on the nature of thinking, but now my immediate concern were with the problem of Artificial Intelligence: How to make machines that think?

\chapter*{Appendix A: Interviews}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix A: Interviews}
\input{chapters/appendix}

\bibliographystyle{apa}
\bibliography{/Users/pythonbuddha/Documents/Thesis/References.bib}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Check the log-file for errors.

Comment: Plese make this into a self contained example. We do not have access to the files you include.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer,  may I ask please how to check log-file?

Comment: open it in your editor and then read it and look for words like "error".

Comment: Log file says:

file:line:error style messages enabled.
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)

Comment: @ daleif, thanks a lot for your reply. There are few files which are part of thesis chapters. Main.tex is the file where I am combining my thesis chapters and putting all the required packages.

Comment: Right, but we can't test the code sample you've posted because we don't actually have those files.  We need you to post something that we can copy-paste and run to see what the problem is.  Look up "minimal working example" for more information.

Comment: comment out each of the `\input` and the `\bibliography` line and then see if it runs without error, if you get an erroreven with that then post it in that form so we can run it, otherwise add the chapters back one at a time until you see which is causing the error. you probably have `\end{document}` in one of the files

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks. your answer helped me.

After checking one by one input method, I found following error even though there are files at perfect location:

Comment: "following error" ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, sorry.

Comment: no need to apologise I just thought you were going to post the error message.  Is this solved now or do you still have a question?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, sorry. Following is the error:

Package hyperref Warning: old lof file detected, not used; run LaTeX again.

pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier ({name{page.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored <to be read again>
\relax

[1]

! LaTeX Error: File `chapters/dedication.tex` not found.

Comment: you can ignore the hyperref warning (for now) but presumably chapters/dedication.tex is missing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102338/discussion-between-python-and-david-carlisle).